# How to transfer data from a userform in one excelsheet to a workbook of other excel file in a sharepoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I would like to know is it possible to transfer the data entered on a User Form in a Excelsheet 'say excel1' to a workbook Excel file located in a SharePoint?

I have attached the coding i tried to make the userform but i am able to do in same excel sheet but not able to trasfer data to other Excel sheet in the SharePoint.

Here, I want to create macros when user clicks on the first Excel sheet the userform should open and  the user fills the form and save data to the Excel sheet this data should directly go to the SharePoint Excel workbook.

Thank you for the Response!

```
Private Sub btnend_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub btnsave_Click()
    Dim ssheet As Worksheet   'giving Name to the sheet

    Set ssheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")  'selecting the worksheet to Transfer data
    Dim nr
    nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'giving row Count to collect data from userform
    nr = nr + 1

    ssheet.Cells(nr, 1) = CDate(Me.tbDate)
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = Me.tbLS
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 3) = Me.tbProject
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 4) = Me.tbbase
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 5) = Me.tbrequest
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 6) = Me.tbtask
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 7) = Me.tbtools
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.tbDate = Date
    'fill boxes
End Sub
```

Comment: You must open workbook with the [Workbooks.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel) from your SharePoint path, then edit the values in that workbook and save/close it. That's all. There is nothing special using SharePoint vs local file. Just give it a try and if you get stuck come back and show what you have tried.

Comment: Sure and thanks! i will get back after giving a try.

Comment: I tried and it is working to open the workbook but not able to Transfer the data to the opened workbook.

Comment: Set ssheet = Workbook.Open(File)                                                              Dim nr                                                                                                             nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row       ##getting error in this line                                                                                                                   nr = nr + 1

Comment: You must define the worksheet `Set ssheet = Workbook.Open(File).Worksheets("SheetName")` or the workbook `Set wb = Workbook.Open(File)` and then the sheet `Set ssheet = wb.Worksheets("SheetName")`

Comment: Super! it worked perfectly as i required. Thanks alot:)